# Custom function is passing my arguments but not invoking querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not getting anything when I run querySelector. When I tried to log my el it's working but the query selector isn't working! I moved my js file at the end, it's still not working

El is being passed around, however, my query selector isn't working!

```js
(function(global) {

  let SimpleShow = function(el) {
    return new SimpleShow.init(el);
  }

  SimpleShow.init = function(el) {
    this.slider = document.querySelector(el);

    //This code isn't working. Nothing is being selected
    console.log(this.slider);
    //However this is working. El is being passed around
    console.log(el);
  }

  global.SimpleShow = SimpleShow;
}(window));


let slideshow = SimpleShow("#gallery");
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.box1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  background: black;
}

.box3 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  background: green;
}

.box4 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <ul>
    <li class="box1"></li>
    <li class="box2"></li>
    <li class="box3"></li>
    <li class="box4"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have no `return` statement in the `.init()` function, so it returns `undefined`.

Comment: No. init is a object. Moreover, console.log should work !

Comment: It is outputting if I put console.log(el)

Comment: It's really unclear what you're saying here. What exactly does/doesn't work?  In the first code block all you do is assign something to a variable.

Comment: I have edited the code. Check the console log area in javascript area. Hope that clarifies my problem

Comment: You just have `console.log(this.slider);` twice and, unsurprisingly, since the first one works the line also works

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It is console.log(el)

Comment: When I turn your code into a snippet, it works fine.

Comment: Are you getting a console.log entry? Mine is completely blank? Nothing is being shown! Not a single div!

Comment: Yes, as-is it works fine. (You can turn it into a snippet yourself if you edit the question.)

Comment: Ohh...it isn't working with chrome right now. Works perfectly with firefox though

Comment: @killerprince182 I edited it to be a snippet, can you confirm the snippet is still not working for you? It's working fine for me

Comment: The snippet is giving me the desired response! Not the chrome browser!